# Spring property with util:property-path as annotation

Tags: java, spring, dao

```
<bean id="groupContainerRelationshipDAO" class="containermanager.management.dao.GroupContainerRelationshipDAOImpl">
   <property name="dataSource">
      <util:property-path path="dataSourceFactory.dataSource" />
   </property>
</bean>
```

I would like to define this as spring annoations. The problem is dataSource is a memeber of the inherited class SimpleJdbcDaoSupport. Does someone knows how to do this?

Comment: are you using hibernate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one:

```
@Component
class GroupContainerRelationshipDAOImpl {

  @Value("#{dataSourceFactory.dataSource}")
  private DataSource dataSource;

}
```

Read more about `@Value` annotation: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-annotation-config